Update XML node value into as lower case using T-SQL in SQL Server
I have a table with one XML data type column.
XML format as below
Table: RootTable
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|Id  | Data                                                 |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|1   | <Root><Id>1</Id><SubRoot>Production</SubRoot></Root> |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|2   |  <Root><Id>1</Id><SubRoot>Test</SubRoot></Root>      |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+

I need to update XML as below
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|Id  | Data                                                 |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|1   | <Root><Id>1</Id><SubRoot>production</SubRoot></Root> |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|2   |  <Root><Id>1</Id><SubRoot>test</SubRoot></Root>      |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+

how to update the SubRoot's value all to lower case using T-SQL in SQL Server?

There is an XQuery function fn:lower-case that can do this
UPDATE 
   RootTable
SET 
   Data.modify('
               replace value of (/Root/SubRoot/text())[. != fn:lower-case(.)][1]
               with
               fn:lower-case((/Root/SubRoot/text())[. != fn:lower-case(.)][1])')
WHERE Data.exist('/Root/SubRoot[text()[1] != fn:lower-case(text()[1])]') = 1;

SQL Fiddle
If there are multiple SubRoot nodes which need updating per row then you need a loop.
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    UPDATE 
        RootTable
    SET 
       Data.modify('
           replace value of (/Root/SubRoot/text())[. != fn:lower-case(.)][1]
           with
           fn:lower-case((/Root/SubRoot/text())[. != fn:lower-case(.)][1])')
    WHERE Data.exist('/Root/SubRoot[text()[1] != fn:lower-case(text()[1])]') = 1;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK;
END;


Wow, I didn't know this lower-case function exists, this makes things far simpler than I wrote in my answer. Deleted mine and thanks for this nice trick!

This is very nice, although a caveat that it only supports one element per xml update, might worth adding that

OK added that..
